# Compiling error of VLC for Android

Tags: android, vlc

When I'm compiling VLC for Android according to this [page](https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile), at the step of:

> sh compile.sh

I get this error:

```
For an ARMv6 device without FPU:
$ export NO_FPU=1
For an ARMv5 device:
$ export NO_ARMV6=1

    If you plan to use a release build, run 'compile.sh release'
    VLC source found
    Building tools
    ./bootstrap: line 63: [: 6b: integer expression expected
    You are ready to build VLC and its contribs
    Building the contribs
    Generating EGL pkg-config file
    Generating GLESv2 pkg-config file
    Guessing build system... x86_64-redhat-linux
    Creating configuration file... config.mak
    Bootstrap completed.

    Run "make" to start compilation.

    Other targets:
     * make install      same as "make"
     * make prebuilt     fetch and install prebuilt binaries
     * make list         list packages
     * make fetch        fetch required source tarballs
     * make fetch-all    fetch all source tarballs
     * make distclean    clean everything and undo bootstrap
     * make mostlyclean  clean everything except source tarballs
     * make clean        clean everything
     * make package      prepare prebuilt packages
    make: Nothing to be done for `fetch'.
    mkdir -p -- /home/heda/adt-bundle/android/vlc/contrib/arm-linux-androideabi/share/aclocal && cd a52dec && autoreconf -fiv -I/home/heda/adt-bundle/android/vlc/contrib/arm-linux-androideabi/share/aclocal
    autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
    autoreconf: configure.in: not using Gettext
    autoreconf: running: aclocal -I /home/heda/adt-bundle/android/vlc/contrib/arm-linux-androideabi/share/aclocal --force 
    aclocal: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'
    autoreconf: configure.in: tracing
    autoreconf: configure.in: not using Libtool
    autoreconf: running: /home/heda/adt-bundle/android/vlc/extras/tools/build/bin/autoconf --include=/home/heda/adt-bundle/android/vlc/contrib/arm-linux-androideabi/share/aclocal --force
    configure.in:74: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_DISABLE_SHARED
          If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
          See the Autoconf documentation.
    configure.in:75: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_LIBTOOL_WIN32_DLL
    configure.in:76: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL
    autoreconf: /home/heda/adt-bundle/android/vlc/extras/tools/build/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1
    make: *** [.a52] Error 1
```

Comment: Some Linux distribution come with their own decades old libtool, try remove this built-in lib from system then run `sh compile.sh` again, the build script will download the up-to-date version then proceed the compilation.

Comment: @yorkw you saved my day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A similar thing happened to me when installing a different package. The fix was to install `libtool` with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libtool
```

then run:

```
$ ./auto_gen.sh
```

then proceed as normal.

Answer (score 5):

I was using Ubuntu 13.04 and after recompiling it in Ubuntu 14.04, the error is gone. I guess it's because the autotools can not updated to the latest version by using apt-get update in 13.04.

Comment: If it fixes the problem, it is a valid answer.  It may not be the best, most universal or only answer, but it is valid.

Comment: I can confirm that this does, in fact, fix the problem.  I was not able to figure out another solution.