# Compile VLC Android fail "You must define ANDROID_NDK, ANDROID_SDK before starting."

Tags: android, libvlc, vlc-android

I get lastest code and step by step from [page](https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile)

```
$ sh compile.sh -a x84
You must define ANDROID_NDK, ANDROID_SDK before starting.
They must point to your NDK and SDK directories.
```

I pointed NDK and SDK on the terminal on Gnome CentOS 7

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuCZO.png]

Comment: what happens when you `echo $ANDROID_NDK $ANDROID_SDK` on the shell

Comment: echo $ANDROID_NDK
->  /home/xxxx/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle
echo $ANDROID_SDK
->  /home/xxxx/Android/Sdk

Comment: you're certain those directories exist?  You can view the compile.sh source code here and it shows where that exist error comes from: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-android/blob/master/compile.sh `if [ -z "$ANDROID_NDK" -o -z "$ANDROID_SDK" ]; then ... fi`

Comment: do an `ls -al $ANDROID_SDK` and `ls -al $ANDROID_NDK` to verify they exist

Comment: I ran ls -al $ANDROID_NDK) and ls -al $ANDROID_SDK that list contents in folder

Comment: Well... I'm running out of ideas haha why not modify compile.sh and echo those variables before the if-statement where they give the error, or even echo them at the top of the script. perhaps they're being unset in the script?... lots of guessing

Comment: Thanks, i set manual.

Comment: also it looks like you were using x84 when perhaps you meant x86 or x86_64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your compile.sh script to see if the variables are being echoed out.  If not, perhaps you'll need to hardcode them in the compile.sh script.  e.g.,

```
ANDROID_NDK=/your/path/android-ndk
ANDROID_SDK=/your/path/android-sdk
```

Comment: I got error autoreconf --install --force --verbose -I m4
./bootstrap: line 78: autoreconf: command not found
vlc: bootstrap failed. I tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24796836/compiling-error-of-vlc-for-android?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: I use CentOS 7 Gnome, how to install apt-get package? I got error mesage  command: apt-get: not found

Comment: maybe `apt-get install autoconf automake` ?

Comment: or, try this `apt-get install -y build-essential`

Comment: bash: apt-get: command not found... I need install apt-get before

Comment: Does centos have yum installed? looks like that may be the case according to google

Comment: replace the apt-get commands with yum... try this `sudo yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'`

Comment: please click the checkbox that is under/below the up/down vote buttons if it answered your original question, thank you!

Comment: i rebuild and got error - autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1

Comment: are there any other errors that are happening? there may be another package you have to install.  If you post this as a new question with the details of all your output you may have better luck.  If it was me, I'd check what version of `autoreconf` is installed and see if it needs to be upgraded.  According to Google the error appears to be somewhat generic. this is certainly a deep rabbit hole haha

Comment: Here are instructions on installing the latest version: https://techglimpse.com/install-update-autoconf-linux-tutorial/ .. I found one online discussion that said CentOS uses an older version so give it a try.

Comment: Libraries have been installed in: /home/xxx/Android/vlc-android/vlc/contrib/i686-linux-android/lib
If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR' flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
- add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable during execution - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   -....

Comment: I don't know what that error message means or what the error is... it sounds like it worked if it say the libraries were installed though.

Comment: I got message  touch .openjpeg
contribs: make failed

Comment: does anything here help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30259182/build-vlc-for-android-project-failed-on-ubuntu-12-04 it could be the centos has old versions of all the tools and you just need to upgrade everything

Comment: _sudo yum update_ and _sudo yum install ant autoconf automake autopoint cmake gawk gcc g++ libtool m4 patch pkg-config libprotobuf-dev libprotobuf-c0-dev protobuf-c-compiler ragel subversion unzip_ . It doesn't work. touch .a52 contribs: make failed